# Fourier Series for $\cos^3(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Consider the familiar trigonometric identity: $\cos^3(x) = \frac{3}{4} \cos(x) + \frac{1}{4} \cos(3x)$

Show that the identity above can be interpreted as Fourier series expansion.

so we know that cos is periodic between $\pi$ and $-\pi$ and $\cos$ is an even function, therefore, $\cos^3$ is even.

so we need to compute $a_0$ ( the integral of $f(x)$ and it will equal $0$) and $a_n$ ( the integral from $\pi$ to $-\pi$ of $\cos^3(x) \cos(nx)$ )

how to compute $a_0$

thanks

Comment: So you want

$$\int \cos^3(x)dx$$

? Asking for clarity's sake

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing in order to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Recall: from a familiar trigonometric identity,

$$\cos^3(x) = \cos(x)\color{blue}{\cos^2(x)} = \cos(x)\color{blue}{(1 - \sin^2(x))}$$

Thus,

$$\int \cos^3(x)dx = \int (1-\sin^2(x))\cos(x)dx$$

Make the $u$-substitution $u = \sin(x), du = \cos(x)dx$ and you should be able to find the result easily. You should get

$$\int \cos^3(x)dx = \sin(x) - \frac 1 3 \sin^3(x) + C$$

Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus on the bounds $0,\pi$. Since $\sin(n\pi) \equiv 0 \; \forall n \in \Bbb Z$,

$$\int_0^\pi \cos^3(x)dx = \sin(0) - \frac 1 3 \sin^3(0) - \left( \sin(\pi) - \frac 1 3 \sin^3(\pi) \right) = 0$$

and thus, $a_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the result given in your question,$$\begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^3 x &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi\left(\frac34 \cos x + \frac 14 \cos 3x\right)\,dx\\
&=\left[\frac34\sin x+\frac1{12}\sin 3x\right]_{-\pi}^\pi\\
&=0\end{align}$$ since $\sin$ of multiples of $\pi$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: While I don't disagree, I think I get the flavor of OP's exercise - "verify the identity using Fourier series." In that light, this is sort of presupposing the conclusion you're trying to prove, if that makes any sense (even if said conclusion is correct).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer yes, that's true, the alternative would be to integrate using $\sin^2x+\cos^2 x=1$ as you did. The question says "familiar identity", so I suppose I assumed that OP knew this identity. I do see what you mean though...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Simply show that$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3 x\cos nx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3 x\sin mx=0$$for $n\ne 1,3$. What about $n=1$ or $n=3$?